# Creating a new List from results of If Statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement

For example if I have a list here:

```
my_list=[abc.txt, def.txt, ghi.jpg]
```

How would I create a new list with just the .txt elements (that are a result of running an if statement, for example if type==.txt)

Comment: changed your list name so it doesn't shadow the builtin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [elem for elem in your_list if elem.endswith('.txt')]
```

Also, don't use `list` as a variable name. You make the built-in `list` function inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> files = ['abc.txt', 'def.txt', 'ghi.jpg']
>>> [x for x in files if x.endswith('.txt')]
['abc.txt', 'def.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

`list(filter(lambda string: string.endswith(".txt"), elements_list))`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another way of doing it:

```
>>> files = ['abc.txt', 'def.txt', 'ghi.jpg']
>>> result = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.txt'), files)
>>> result
['abc.txt', 'def.txt']
```